# Magento2 keeps redirecting to 127.0.0.1

Tags: redirection, docker, magento

I've installed Magento in two Docker containers on a Mac, using the Docker install script provided by Magento. Docker provides two IP numbers, one for the host using 127.0.0.1 and a port number (32772 in this case, the exposed port number for the host), the other in the 172.x.x.x range (here 172.17.0.2).

I logged in, changed some trivial value. Then I committed both docker engines (Magento and Mysql) and saved them to a tar file. I loaded these files in docker on a Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. After some initial errors, and restarts of both docker engines it should have worked, but it fails on one point. When I load the website in a browser, it gets redirected to 127.0.0.1:32772, which doesn't work. Magento handles this redirect, so in a way it works.

Magento is setup to redirect to one URL. This URL or IP is set in a table and is set to the right value (172.17.0.2). Normally this means that the redirect should be to 172.17.0.2, port 80.

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%';
```

The cache is cleared:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

Browser cache is cleared (completely removed the .mozilla folder), tried a private window as well, and I installed another browser just to make sure.

On the magento2 docker container I installed elinks, a command line browser, and this opens the site and admin of magento using http://localhost. I see the admin login form. If I open the site in the host browser, it redirects from 172.17.0.2 to 127.0.0.1:32772, including a session ID. This means that magento runs and generates this session ID, but I don't understand the redirect.

Then there is this exposed port numer, 32772. This is the one that is set on the Mac, and I bet this is not the number that is used on the Ubuntu install.

1. Why does the redirect keep happening?
2. How can I get this site working properly?
3. Where is the exposed port number set and can I change it for a running conatiner?
4. How can I get the proper port number for the current container?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, on ubuntu_16.04 and after I tried the solution of this  thread [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639544/magento-is-automatically-redirecting-to-localhost-on-live-server#17653419), I tried these:

When you are on Magento Admin Page  ***127.0.0.1/admin/...***

1)Go to System --> Cache Management

2)Click on the button **Flush Magento Cache** and

3)try again the no_127.0.0.1 url